# PHP printing raw string

Tags: php, html

I need to print CURL headers as a raw string, so with all of the `\n` and `\r` anyone could tell me how to?

I tried `print_r` and few other but it hasn't worked

Comment: You want to print on paper, print on the client browser?

Comment: You could wrap it inside a <pre> element, assuming you are using html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure exactly what you're after, but you might try:

```
$headers = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array("\\r","\\n"),$headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `var_export` function:

```
echo var_export($s, true);
```